# React Native + Api Entity (ASP.Net) - JSON Parse Error: Unrecognized Token

Tags: asp.net, api, react-native

I am new using native react, I am developing a project that consists in showing the data of an Api in my project. I have seen tutorials and most, if not all, use the same Api:  [image: API]

But what I want is to be able to show the data of a local API that connects to a local BD as well, which is why I developed a Web API with ASP.Net, I was guided by this [image: tutorial]

Create a DB in SQL Server (which is the DB that I want to use for this project) and generate the API; the API works correctly, tested with POSTMAN.

[image: BD SQL Server]    [image: WEB API]    [image: Postman]

Now the problem is that I want to use it in my project, and following the tutorial that is on the official page of React Native in the [image: NetWorking] section does not work for me.

This is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList, ActivityIndicator, Text, View  } from 'react-native';

export default class FetchExample extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={ isLoading: true}
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    return fetch('http://192.168.2.19:53943/api/users')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          dataSource: responseJson.users,
        }, function(){

        });

      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render(){

    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return(
        <View style={{flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator/>
        </View>
      )
    }

    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop:20}}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.Name}, {item.Email}</Text>}
          keyExtractor={({id}, index) => id}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The error message that I get when I execute my project is [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/802Ks.jpg)

> JSON Parse Error: Unrecognized Token

What could I be doing wrong? I suspect that it may be the URL that happened to the FETCH, since it eliminates all of the render () and only leaves a  showing a message and the same error keeps coming up. Thank you

Comment: You can check your offending JSON using a tool like this one: https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

hi you shuld add  this code in  Global.asax Application_Start() :

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

and add  this code in WebApiConigg :

```
 var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

rest visual stdio and run again project WebApi address

stop  react-native emulator => cntrl+ c react-native-run-android